# ELK Stack: Logstash shows that it's receiving log entries from Filebeat, but Elasticsearch is not creating my index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am new to the ELK stack and I wanted to try and test it out to see if I wanted to use it. I have elasticsearch, kibana, and logstash installed on one virtual machine and I have filebeat and nginx installed on another virtual machine.

I have a custom log format for my nginx access.log that looks like this:

```
<IP> - - [21/Dec/2023:00:46:10 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.1 Safari/605.1.15" "-" "<IP>" sn="test.com" rt=0.000 ua="-" us="-" ut="-" ul="-" cs=-

#log format

log_format  main_ext  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
'"$host" sn="$server_name" '
'rt=$request_time '
'ua="$upstream_addr" us="$upstream_status" '
'ut="$upstream_response_time" ul="$upstream_response_length" '
'cs=$upstream_cache_status' ;
```

I have everything configured and have the Kibana dashboard up and running with data being sent to the dashboard. The only problem I am having is that the correct indexes are not showing up in elasticsearch or my kibana dashboard. The only index that is showing up is the default filebeat-* and I am not able to see my nginx-access-logs or nginx-error-logs indices.

Here is my logstash config file path /etc/logstash/conf.d/beats.conf and here is what it looks like:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGLINE}" }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }

  if [type] == "nginxaccess" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} - - \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "%{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}" %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:bytes} "%{URI:referrer}" "%{DATA:agent}" "%{IPORHOST:x_forwarded_for}" sn="%{DATA:sn}" rt=%{NUMBER:request_time} ua="%{DATA:upstream_addr}" us="%{DATA:upstream_status}" ut="%{DATA:upstream_response_time}" ul="%{DATA:upstream_response_length}" cs=%{DATA:upstream_cache_status}' }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z", "ISO8601" ]
    }
  }

  if [type] == "nginxerror" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{WORD:log_level}\] %{NUMBER:pid}#%{NUMBER:tid}: %{GREEDYDATA:message}' }
    }
    date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}



output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

And here is what my etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml file looks like:

```
filebeat.inputs:

#Each - is an input. Most options can be set at the input level, so
#you can use different inputs for various configurations.
#Below are the input-specific configurations.

#filestream is an input for collecting log messages from files.
- type: filestream
  #Unique ID among all inputs, an ID is required.
  id: my-filestream-id
  #Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: true
  #Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
  fields:
    type: syslog

- type: filestream
  id: nginx-access-logs
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nginx/access.log*
  fields:
    type: nginxaccess  # Set the log type to nginx_access
    beat: nginxaccess

- type: filestream
  id: nginx-error-logs
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/nginx/error.log*
  fields:
    type: nginxerror  # Set the log type to nginx_error
    beat: nginxerror

filebeat.config.modules:
  #Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  #Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1

setup.kibana:

output.logstash:
  #The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["<IP>:5044"]

processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
```

Now after configuring those files I restarted both logstash and filebeat and ran the commands:

`sudo filebeat setup --index-management -E output.logstash.enabled=false -E 'output.elasticsearch.hosts=[":9200"]'

sudo filebeat setup -E output.logstash.enabled=false -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=[':9200'] -E setup.kibana.host=:5601`

Then I went and checked my indexes and my nginx-access-logs and nginx-error-logs were still not showing in my indices. The only ones that show are the default filebeat-*

`curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v" health status index                                 uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size dataset.size yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.20                   _nckH4WZSmuaI1umnjVR-w   1   1      91772            0     36.1mb         36.1mb       36.1mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.14                   yA8Sl4lXSYG_vB8d67Cqfg   1   1      47876            0     19.6mb         19.6mb       19.6mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.15                   OwUwZMdBR3myvZkuvUgF2A   1   1      75513            0     28.5mb         28.5mb       28.5mb yellow open   .ds-filebeat-8.11.2-2023.12.08-000001 PPRThZq3RIK490NVmW605A   1   1          0            0       249b           249b         249b yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.16                   4EOUSNCKRlOzAy1zdih6hg   1   1      79795            0     29.4mb         29.4mb       29.4mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.17                   JL7TRkUgTzeGbT-M0bBD5g   1   1      64067            0     24.4mb         24.4mb       24.4mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.10                   m3aWcEayTnu3r_iTxd_5aA   1   1      77669            0     27.9mb         27.9mb       27.9mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.21                   mvbk8wNiQ9-rT9Vs-W-Vqg   1   1      62321            0     27.9mb         27.9mb       27.9mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.11                   bXq4al_xQ62eMjAnEKR5Xw   1   1      81750            0       29mb           29mb         29mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.12                   V2ojtGRTR4ixSGT_tgkhHg   1   1      70454            0       27mb           27mb         27mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.13                   eRuR2uf2QdqF00VagDnjpw   1   1      72317            0     27.4mb         27.4mb       27.4mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.18                   Q_IEBhszSOSK9305LsvXOg   1   1      82494            0     30.5mb         30.5mb       30.5mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.19                   KsJZ2um5Q8e7v2ckP9MlGA   1   1      77330            0     29.6mb         29.6mb       29.6mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.08                   C8ih6TUMRdm2AsSO5idwkw   1   1      13953            0      5.8mb          5.8mb        5.8mb yellow open   filebeat-2023.12.09                   2Taw_nROSCiBeYJFk-kyXA   1   1      58190            0     21.2mb         21.2mb       21.2mb`

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong or what is going on. I am lost at this point!